# How to fill the values of the inner points of a (numpy) meshgrid as an interpolation of the values at the borders?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Say we have a meshgrid:

```py
import numpy as np

u = np.zeros((5, 5))

# borders
u[ 0,  :] = np.array([ 1.0,  2.0,  4.5,  8.0, 12.5])
u[-1,  :] = np.array([ 1.0,  4.0,  9.0, 16.0, 25.0])
u[ :,  0] = np.array([ 1.0,  2.0,  4.5,  2.0,  1.0])
u[ :, -1] = np.array([12.5, 17.0, 22.0, 23.5, 25.0])

print(u)
```

```
[[ 1.   2.   4.5  8.  12.5]  
 [ 2.   0.   0.   0.  17. ]  
 [ 4.5  0.   0.   0.  22. ]  
 [ 2.   0.   0.   0.  23.5]  
 [ 1.   4.   9.  16.  25. ]]
```

[image]

How can I fill the inner nodes with the combination/blend/interpolation of the values at the borders? (I don't want the surface, only the values. The plot is for visual assistance.)

**Edit**: actually, I found a workaround. One can do a linear interpolation at each opposite pair veritcally and an other horizontally. Then, take the mean of the two:

```py
# vertical interpolation
y_borders_values = np.array([0, 4])
u_vert_borders_values = np.array([[u[ 0,  i], u[-1,  i]] for i in range(5)])
yvals = np.arange(5)

uy_inter = np.zeros_like(u)
for column in range(5):
    uy_inter[:, column] = np.interp(yvals, y_borders_values, 
                                    u_vert_borders_values[column])

# horizontal interpolation
x_borders_values = np.array([0, 5])
u_hor_borders_values = np.array([[u[i,  0], u[i,  -1]] for i in range(5)])
xvals = np.arange(5)

ux_inter = np.zeros_like(u)
for row in range(5):
    ux_inter[row, :] = np.interp(xvals, x_borders_values, 
                                 u_hor_borders_values[row])

# final interpolation as the mean of verical and horizontal
u[1:-1, 1:-1] = (uy_inter[1:-1, 1:-1] + ux_inter[1:-1, 1:-1]) / 2
```

Visualizing the result:
[image]

(**Edit** after Matthew's note on the wording)

But, is there any tool that does something like that with less code?

Comment: Your question is really undefined.  You can have an infinite number of 'solutions' that satisfy the boundary nodes.  What is more 'optimized' depends on the problem and question.  Your solution is probably fine if it is just 'for the eye'.  If it represents some data that can be represented roughly by Laplace's equation, you could solve the PDE given the boundary data and fill in the values that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is the question undefined? I nead to initialize the grid to some good initial values, that represend the boundaries. So, my question is more open to alternatives. There are many solutions to make a surface out of 4 boundaries. I would like to know if there is anything that does something like that with far less code. Maybe scipy would have something, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I was working off of the language of 'more optimized' being more optimal solution.